# Convert String to int[] array

Tags: java, arrays, string, types, converters

how could I convert my String to int array?
my input:

```
String numbers = "123456";
```

What I'd like to reach:

```
Int numbers[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

That String was splitted from String with this number.

Comment: Assuming this to be in Java?

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language you're using. @AnushBM guessed Java, but there are several languages that look similar. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a String into an Integer\[\] array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694806/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 one liner would be:

```
int[] integers = Stream.of( numbers.split("") )
  .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
  .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above question is for Java.

```
 String numbers = "123456";
    int[] array = new int[numbers.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) {
            array[i] = Character.getNumericValue(numbers.charAt(i));
            System.out.println("\n"+array[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are working with. But I can tell you in c++.

character codes of digits start from 48(dec). You can add and remove this value for each element.

The code could roughly look like this.

```
int * _numbers=new int[numbers.size()];
for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++)
    _numbers[i]=numbers[i]-48;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to create an array variable and loop through the string characters and push them into the array.

```js
var str = "123456";
var arr = [];

for (let n of str) {
  arr.push(parseInt(n))
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are more straightforward ways to do achieve this; however, you can also take the substring of the array between a value of i and i+1, parse that string as an integer, and then assign the array at index i to the value of the integer to achieve the same goal. Here is the code below:

```
    public class StringtoIntArray {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            String numbers = "123456";
            int[] array = new int[numbers.length()];

            String temp; 
            int holder;

            for(int i=0;i<numbers.length();i++)
            {
                temp=numbers.substring(i,i+1);
                holder = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                array[i]=holder;
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```